# how to create a "STATIC LIBRARY" or a framework out of my source code

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, static-libraries

i have developed a complete project for iPad and now i want the same source code to be used in my clients project but i dont want to share my source code with them. I found out that we can create some static libraries in order to accomplish this task.Can anyone help me with the process of creating a static library out of the source code which is already available with me.

Comment: take a look at http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Comment: i,v already seen it but , it does not tell us how to convert the available code into a static library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer I posted on external libraries. Although the question specifically relates to creating a fat binary it has some links to a tutorial site, plus Apple's guidelines.

[iPhone external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728945/iphone-external-library/7729053#7729053)

You'll also find tons of related questions on Stack Overflow, for example:

[How to create a static library from an Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624604/how-to-create-a-static-library-from-an-xcode-project)

Best thing is to do a search along the lines of "how to create iPhone static library". You should find lots of helpful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some stuff out of here,

http://dev.byteclub.com/blog/1-iphone-sdk/48-how-to-almost-create-your-own-iphone-os-framework

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html

[How do I create an iPhone framework and use it in other iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004817/how-do-i-create-an-iphone-framework-and-use-it-in-other-iphone-applications)